# FTP server tool in my local computer

Tags: ftp

My goal is to use a ftp server software in my local computer as a simulation before initiating in production phase.

Just wondering if FileZilla is the right ftp server tool to be acting as simulation

Thank you!

Comment: It's probably fine, you just need any old FTP server for your application to connect to, right?

Comment: Your question is too general. But I think the answer to your question is YES, FileZilla should meet your needs, it is a pretty good FTP server in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the OS that you have on your local computer.

Even if you are using MAC, Windows or Linux you can use FileZilla. So, answer for your question is "yes". FileZilla is probably the most common and popular ftp server tool around.